# Do users need to fulfill any prerequisites to run C++17 software?

Tags: c++, deployment, c++17

My team and I are currently developing a piece of software that is built on C++14 specs. We are considering adding some C++17 features (primarily `std::variant`s) in our code, but my supervisor was unsure if we could simply put these in our code, build with an appropriate compiler and then ship it.

From what I know, this should not make any difference if we pre-compile our application for our target platforms and make them available as executables, but I have never actually had to deal with deployment of software to customers yet, so I am unsure if I am overlooking anything here (like if we would have to also supply according C++ redistributables for Windows or so).

As background info: our software is heavily Qt-based and should thus be deployable to all major desktop operating systems. We're mainly working in a Windows environment, and for most testing purposes we are compiling with MSVC2017 at the moment.

We technically also plan to release an SDK/library to facilitate interfacing with the network part of our application, which may also benefit from C++17 features. I would assume that developers willing to use this SDK would then be forced to use a C++17-compliant build environment, even if the C++17 features are pretty much encapsulated in the library and not exposed in the headers - is that correct?

Comment: @Ron Question is about running software, not building it. Read before posting.

Comment: @Ivan that may be the title but the question is about code.

Comment: @drescherjm Both question and title are about distributing and running software.

Comment: ***We are considering adding some C++17 features (primarily std::variants) in our code,*** Is about code.

Comment: The question is about both -- distributing software to end users, with the important point that the end users may integrate with the software using an SDK. So this is not about OP's build process, it's about (potentially) the end user's build process as they try to extend the software.

Comment: One important issue is if you use code that requires a newer compiler than your customers are using they may not be able to use your SDK.

Comment: @drescherjm I am aware of backwards compatibility not being given if we distribute a C++17-based SDK, but what did you mean by the CRT and runtimes mixing issues?

Comment: You are basically forcing your users to use the newer compiler for their software. Either that or or they need to isolate your software from their applications (to get around the CRT and ABI incompatibilities). @cdhowie wrote about that here: ***Regardless of whether you use C++17 features, your SDK users should use exactly the same C++ environment (including the version, if possible***

Comment: @drescherjm ah, right. That is definitely a valid concern and we'll probably have to get some feedback from our customers first on whether their build environments are already on that state.

Comment: With that said there is supposed to be binary compatibility (with 2 limitations) between 2015 and 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017

Comment: @drescherjm Great point. I've stolen that link for my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is (as usual) "it depends."

If the C++17 features being used are built entirely from templates, and C++17 types/features are not exposed in your SDK header, then this absolutely should work fine, since the templates would be instantiated and included in your library's native code by *your* compiler.

If the C++17 features depend on some runtime library support, but are not exposed in your SDK, then you would just need to ship that runtime library or otherwise make it available.

Regardless of whether you use C++17 features, your SDK users should use exactly the same C++ environment (including the version, if possible) that you use, because there is no guarantee of ABI-compatibility between C++ versions, nor between different versions of the same compiler.  If you use MSVC++2017, your SDK users must also use either MSVC++2017 or another environment that is [explicitly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017) to be compatible with the MSVC++2017 ABI.  (So instead of asking if this will work, you should be asking what version of MSVC++ it is reasonable to require your SDK users to use, and that's a question I cannot answer for you.)

In all cases, end users who are *not* intending to use the SDK should be fine as long as you ship the required runtime libraries, which you are almost certainly already doing (though you may need to change which runtime library you ship).

Comment: Since different versions of MSVC use incompatible runtimes, runtime has to be shipped either way.

Comment: @Ivan That's what I was trying to get at, editing to be a bit more clear on that point. I'm also trying to keep the language environment-neutral, as the same general logic applies to other C++ environments, not just MSVC.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the runtimes to be shipped are made available as a by-product of telling the compiler to build for release, or do they have to be bundled up separately from somewhere?

Comment: @Sty MSVC has a redistributable installer that is typically bundled automatically if you build your installer (MSI) from within Visual Studio. Otherwise, you need to make sure that the redistributable runs as part of your install process.  Compiling for release doesn't do anything magic regarding the runtime libraries, it just omits some debugging information and may enable additional code optimizer flags.

Comment: @cdhowie good to know. I'm mainly building out of QtCreator, which only interfaces with the installed MSVC kits, but I recall seeing some installer-generation options in there too, so I guess I'll go look for these when deploying for customers.

Comment: @Sty I would suggest having an unpatched Windows 7 VM that you can test the installer on.  It shouldn't have the MSVC++2017 runtimes, so it's a good environment to test to make sure that you've bundled all of your dependencies.

Comment: @cdhowie that is a reasonable suggestion, I will see towards having such a setup added to our build server. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Sty No problem. It goes without saying that as part of your QA process, you should test the installer on every configuration you want to support.

Comment: Most toolchains give far more guarantees than "is reasonably consistent with itself". The time of C++ ABIs changing every five minutes and everyone having their own collection of them are over. Though as C++ interfaces are significantly more complex than C, so is the ABI.